# AWS - Non-Editable Launch Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want to know if is it possible to have a launch template where the IAM users can't modify this template (specially the KeyPair .pem), it's possible via policy ?

If is not, what is the best way to create an ec2 with default non-editable params (the iam users have just to push a button or launch a command), lambda, other service ?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of edit-ability in cloud computing boils down to the concept of [RBAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control)

You want to use RBAC's from AWS IAM to limit who can do what to what. In this case I suggest you read up on [IAM Policies & Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html)

One simple strategy is to assign EC2 LC edit capabilities to only the roles you want- and for the others you limit that ability in the policies they have.

Another effective strategy is to implement [Access Control Boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html) in conjunction with having explicit policies.

As for the best way to deploy EC2 LC Templates without allowing IAM roles from modifying the template- once you have implemented the correct permissions and policies, the users that are allowed to launch machines without being able to edit the configuration can do so in the multitude of ways AWS allows.

Comment: The users of my IAM have all their own key pair, and i have an other key pair developer.pem for developer access. I have a template EC2 each user can launch it. But, i want to force this template with my key pair developer.pem. How you can do that with policy ?

Comment: The pem key is set in the Launch Configuration- if you want to set the Launch Configuration to only launch EC2 machines with a certain key. Then set it. But for the other IAM users who have permission to launch machines with that Launch Configuration- you disable their ability to edit the Launch Configuration- so they cannot change the pem key and have to use the one that is set. The steps for this policy creation are outlined clearly in the Policies and Permissions link I've attached in the answer.